# Problema com o bodyParser - Não pega o req.body mesmo com bodyparser instalado e configurado

Tags: node.js, express.js

Estou tentando criar minha primeira API REST MVC com NodeJs e Express, só que eu não consigo pegar as informações do req.body, o bodyParser está configurado. Já pesquisei de tudo e não encontro o problema, segue o link do github do meu projeto. Queria muito ajuda, porfavor.

https://github.com/Thiagosousadev/posts

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Importante você [edit] seu post e explicar detalhadamente o problema com um [mcve]. Estudar a postagem disponível neste link pode fazer uma diferença muito positiva no seu aproveitamento do site: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Boa noite Thiago,parabéns pela inciativa no mundo Node.js,aqui vai uma dica oara sua carreira como DEV sempre coloque os middlewares que recebem os dados,antes das rotas:

```
    //BodyParser
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

    app.use(bodyParser.json())**

    // Configurações
    // Banco de Dados

    require('./database/database');

    //Engine e frontend
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
   app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
   app.use(express.static('public'));
   //app.use(expressLayouts);
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder, mas eu fiz o que recomendou e infelizmene continua o mesmo erro. Eu utlizo o Postman pra testar a API. Vou mandar os prints do postman.

Comment: Eu agradeço se você enviar,vai ser interessante ver o que há de errado....

Comment: Ele retorna na rota post como um json vazio: { }

Comment: Ja tentou enviar os dados usando POST ?,ali o método esta GET,o envio de dados por padrão usa POST.

Comment: Sim eu corrigi e funcionou, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Eu que agradeço,continue tentando eu vi o seu código e você programa muito bem,e faz subdivisão dos arquivos nas pastas de maneira profissional.

Comment: Muito obrigado, na verdade eu percebi que o erro estava no meu arquivo js estatico, eu fiz primeiro o front end simples e usei o innerHTML pra apagar os campos de input quando clicar no botão, ai toda vez que eu enviava o form pra rota post ele apagava tudo que estava nos inputs e por isso enviava um objeto vazio. Obrigado pela ajuda e por avaliar meu codigo, me ajuda muito a melhorar.

Comment: É nóis !!!!! Vida longa aos DEV's !!!!!